# Loop through a range of cells on cell change to show next number in the sequence as cell's new value

Tags: vba, excel

I understand how to loop through a range,

```
For Each cell In Range("A1:A5")
    If [condition] Then
    End If
Next
```

And I'm aware of OnChange event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A6")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call Macro
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I am not sure as to how achieve the following effect: 
I have a cell A6 which shows the 'result' of formula, and I have another cell A7 with current **interest rate** which is used in the formula, I have multiple interest rates to go through, so I've declared them as a range (Interest_Rates).

My question is, how can I go through declared range to go to the next number once the A6 cell's value has changed, and print it in cell A7 to get the result for another interest rate in the range, so I can print it in the table, and then find the highest rate.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want a worksheet_change event.  It sounds like you want to just loop through each cell in the Interest_Rates range, put the value in cell A7 and do a `Worksheets("Sheetname").Calculate` line to get the formula to update and then copy just the value of A6 to wherever your results table is.

Comment: Sadly, the formula has cells which cannot be defined, that's why I was considering using worksheet_change event, so when the result in A7 changes, set the value of A6 cell to a new interest. I would love to have it as a loop, but I am not sure if it's possible due to the formula which has cells that need to represent their row, e.g. B1, B2, B3 as formula is executed down the column. I do apologise if I am not making any sense.

Comment: At this point you'll need to provide sample data and expected results.  Your description still leads me to believe that my proposed solution will work though.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a sample code of your execution? (Just to get the idea) 
Here is the example: Interest_Range has "3.4%, 4.5%, 6.4%"
Formula is =SUM(B3/100*Interest_Range) = Result, which is shown in A6, however, I need to execute this formula for every number in the Interest_Range. What I do then, I have a table in another Sheet with 'Formula Results', where every result is recorded. Does this clear it a little?

Comment: Can you just use [Excel's "Data Table" feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-e95e2487-6ca6-4413-ad12-77542a5ea50b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to make some assumptions.  For example, the code assumes that your formula is in cell A6 and that it actually looks like this: `=SUM(B3/100*A7)`.  It also assumes that the formula is on a sheet named "Sheet1" and it puts the results in sheet "Formula Results" in column A.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rInterestCell As Range
    Dim rDest As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Formula Results")

    For Each rInterestCell In Range("Interest_Range").Cells
        wsData.Range("A7").Value = rInterestCell.Value  'Put the interest cell value in range A7, which is used by the formula in A6
        wsData.Calculate    'Update the formula result based on the new value in A7
        Set rDest = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        If rDest.Row < 6 Then Set rDest = wsDest.Range("A6")    'Guarantee that A6 is the starting cell for the results
        rDest.Value = wsData.Range("A6").Value   'Put the value only in a new row in the destination sheet
    Next rInterestCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much! Just one more request, is it possible to make sure the results start on A6 instead of A2? If I change Offset to (1,3), it will place it on Column 3, and if I change 1 to 3, it will add 3 rows of spacing between every value.

Comment: @zafira.404 I have updated the answer to guarantee that 'Formula Results'!A6 is the starting cell for the results.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, Tigeravatar. Do you happen to know how to include two conditions in For Each statement? It successfully runs through a single range, but is it possible to include another range, as it is involved in the formula, and continue printing rDest.Value as it is? I want to repeat the exact solution but for two cells with different ranges, that are all linked to the main formula. e.g. A7 = Interest_Range Value and A8 = Deposit_Range. Would this require another For Each statement with some IF statements? Could you please assist me with this problem, thank you.

Comment: @zafira.404 That is a different problem with different requirements.  Please start a new thread to address that issue.